# Draw UIBezierPath in small view

Tags: ios, drawrect, uibezierpath, catransform3d

I have signature view, when signature is done I reduce view and save UIBezierPath. When I set UIBezierPath to small view and call setNeedsDisplay, view doesn't draw lines. Maybe problem in scale?
Big view
[image]
Reduced view
[image]
After setting path and calling setNeedsDisplay
[image]

Comment: To clarify, is `drawRect:` called after you call `setNeedsDisplay`?

Comment: @brigadir  Yes. When parent view appears I set UIBezierPath and make setNeedsDisplay and  drawRect works.

Comment: In this case the problem is inside drawing operation. I would propose to draw bounding rect of signature path, set larger stroke, etc. to determine what exactly works wrong.

Comment: You can also snapshot the big signature view as an image and then apply it anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use:

```
self.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1./3., 1./3., 1);
```

this will make your view 3 times smaller but the actual drawing will be in same size, so coordinates in your path wont be messed up.

For showing SignatureView just make the scale normal like this:

```
self.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
```

Good luck ;)